# Pandas datatype change within a function

Tags: python, pandas

### General background

I've written a function which incorporates a MySQL query, with some munging on the returned data (pulled into a pandas df).

```
enginedb =create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pswd@10.0.10.26:3306/db", 
                   encoding='latin1')

query = ("""Select blah blah""")

df = pd.read_sql(query, enginedb)
```

This works fine - the query is a significant one with multiple joins etc.. However, it transpired for a certain lot within the db, the datatype was off: for almost all 'normal' lots, the datatypes for the columns were `int64`, some `object`, a `datetime64[ns]`... but for one lot (so far), all but the datetime were returning as `object`.

### Issue

I need to do a stack - one of the columns is a list, and i've got some code to take each item of the list and stack them down row by row:

```
cols = list(df)
cols = cols[:-1]   
df_stack = df.set_index(cols)['data'].apply(pd.Series).stack()
```

The problem is this doesn't work for this 'odd' lot, with the non-standard datatypes (*the reason for the non-std data types is due to an upstream ETL process and i can't affect that*).
The exact error is:
`'Series' object has no attribute 'stack'`

Consequently I had incorporated an `if/else` statement, checking to see if the dtype of one of the cols is incorrect, and if so, change it:

```
if df['id'].dtype == 'int64':
            df_stack = df.set_index(cols)['data'].apply(pd.Series).stack()
            df_stack = df_stack.reset_index()

else:
     df_stack = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce') 
# it can't be more specific than for all the columns, as there are a LOT
```

But this is having no effect - i've included in the function (containing the query and subsequent munging) a print out statement of `dy.dtypes` and `df_stack.dtypes` and the function is having no effect.

### Why is this?

#### EDIT

I've added this picture to show the code (at right) which is attempting to catch the incorrectly-dtyped lot (12384), and the print-outs before and after the `pd.to_numeric` function (which both show just objects, no numeric cols).

[image]

### My underlying questions has two parts:

1. What would cause `'Series' object has no attribute 'stack'`? (more fundamentally than wrong datatype - or at least why is datatype an issue?)
2. Why would a pd.numeric not cause any change here?

Comment: Could you provide some input data and expected output?

Comment: I've added some outputs - it's hard to give example input data (privacy issues aside), but hopefully this shows the issue

Comment: Ideally you should provide an input dataframe with an expected output, otherwise its impossible to reproduce your issue.. Regarding to your last question, you can't apply stack to a Series.

Comment: I'm more interested if people have seen this before abstractly - not solving my specific issue (although that would be nice!) and why it happens. Regarding your second statement - it does work for the other ones

Comment: It works with the others because they are probably dataframes.

Comment: It works with the 'odd' lot - when not in a function; if i run the command on the standalone dataframe the line works, and the conversion works

Comment: It will work as long as it is a DataFrame. Not when it is a Series.

Comment: I was not pulling any data - so technically it was not a series (no data) but as there were column headers, yes it was a df (i presume?). Thanks - i've upvoted your comments as a thanks.